# How to get FirstName and LastName from the user's Microsoft account authenticated using Asp.Identity in MVC5 application

Tags: authentication, external, identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a MVC 5 application, and I'm able to authenticate the user using microsoft External login which is an out of box feature. I have observed that by authenticating the user using microsoft account, UserName and Email are stored in database with the same value(i.e., Email for both of them). How do i retreive FirstName, LastName, from the registered microsoft account.